# Error in installation a R package

Tags: r, installation, package

Please help me, I cannot install "MASS" package.

```
> library(MASS)
Error in library(MASS) : there is no package called ‘MASS’
```

I tried to install MASS package from local:

```
> utils:::menuInstallLocal()  
package ‘MASS’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked  
Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package ‘MASS’
```

Even I cannot remove "MASS":

```
> remove.packages("MASS")  
Removing package from ‘C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.1/library’  
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)  
Error in find.package(pkgs, lib) : there is no package called ‘MASS’
```

Also with this option I couldn't install package:

```
> options(install.lock=T)  
> utils:::menuInstallLocal()  
package ‘MASS’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked  
Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package ‘MASS’  
Warning: restored ‘MASS’  
Warning message:  
In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :  
  problem copying C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\library\00LOCK\MASS\libs\x64\MASS.dll to C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\library\MASS\libs\x64\MASS.dll: Permission
```

And with install.packages:

```
> install.packages("C:\\MASS_7.3-35.zip",repos=NULL)
package ‘MASS’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked  
Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package ‘MASS’  
Warning: restored ‘MASS’  
Warning message:  
In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :  
  problem copying C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\library\00LOCK\MASS\libs\x64\MASS.dll to C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\library\MASS\libs\x64\MASS.dll: Permission
```

I should mention I use R with ORE (Oracle R Enterprise).

Comment: Why don't you use the usual way, i.e. `install.packages("MASS", dependencies=TRUE)`?

Comment: I haven't access to Internet, our server is separate from Internet Network.

Comment: You should prefer `install.packages("dir/package_name", repos = NULL)` where `dir/` is the directory you downloaded the zip file `package_name`.

Comment: Can you run R as an administrator?

Comment: Yes, I can use admin user.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

There could be a few things happening here.  Start by first figuring out your library location:

```
Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER")
```

or

```
.libPaths()
```

We already know yours from the info you gave: **C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\library**

I believe you have a file in there called: `00LOCK`.  From `?install.packages`:

> Note that it is possible for the package installation to fail so badly that the lock directory is not removed: this inhibits any further installs to the library directory (or for --pkglock, of the package) until the lock directory is removed manually.

You need to delete that file.  If you had the `pacman` package installed you could have simply used `p_unlock()` and the `00LOCK` file is removed.  You can't install `pacman` now until the `00LOCK` file is removed.

To install `pacman` use:

```
install.packages("pacman")
```

There may be a second issue.  This is where you somehow corrupted `MASS`.  This can occur, in my experience,  if you try to update a package while it is in use in another R session.  I'm sure there's other ways to cause this as well.  To solve this problem try:

1. Close out of all R sessions (use task manager to ensure you're truly R session free) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>
2. Go to your library location `Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER")`. In your case this is: **C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\library**
3. Manually delete the `MASS` package
4. Fire up a vanilla session of R
5. Install `MASS` via `install.packages("MASS")`

If any of this works please let me know what worked.

Comment: The part that worked for me was to quit RStudio, delete the package from the libs directory and re-install from vanilla R. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why I don't have such directory on my cp as `Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER")` says?

Comment: Check system task manager section worked for me. Luckily didn't have to get to the second issue.

Comment: Step 1. Close ALL sessions. This one just got me for the 100th time. Thanks and pre-emptive thanks for the next time.

Comment: @variable This was the ONLY thing that worked for me: deleting manually from the directory. As I got tired of doing that, finally `pak::pak()` worked.

Answer (score 30):

I had the same problem with e1071 package. Just close any other R sessions running parallelly and you will be good to go.

Comment: This worked. Multiple R sessions can really cause problems. I was running a for loop on another R session and trying to install packages on another and this error just persisted until I closed the sessions

Comment: In my case, I had to stop a running Shiny server.

Comment: And Julia sessions (if you used `RCall`)

Answer (score 3):

The [solution indicated by Guannan Shen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52249712/1169233) has one drawback that usually goes unnoticed.

When you run `sudo R` in order to run `install.packages()` as superuser, the directories in which you install the library end up belonging to `root` user, a.k.a., the superuser.

So, next time you need to update your libraries, you will not remember that you ran `sudo`, therefore leaving `root` as the owner of the files and directories; that eventually causes the error when trying to move files, because no one can overwrite `root` but themself.

That can be averted by running

```
sudo chown -R yourusername:yourusername *
```

in the directory `lib` that contains your local libraries, replacing `yourusername` by the adequated value in your installation.  Then you try installing once again.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the installation of `nlme` package is in trouble:

```
mv: cannot move '/home/guanshim/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/nlme' 
to '/home/guanshim/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/00LOCK-nlme/nlme': 
Permission denied
```

Using **Ubuntu 18.04**, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal window:

```
sudo R
install.packages('nlme')
q()
```

Answer (score 1):

After using the wrong quotation mark characters in `install.packages()`, correcting the quote marks yielded the "cannot remove prior installation" error. Closing and restarting R worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to close R session and reinstall all packages. In that session I worked with large tables, I suspect this might have had the effect.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add my own experience with this error.

I recently updated R using `installR` within the RGui as recommended but during the installation process, the GUI froze.

When I launched RStudio the next time to get some work done, most of my packages needed to be manually deleted and re-installed. Seems they did not get moved over.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar situation and received the following error while creating a new RMD file in Rstudio:

> <U+2714> Package 'xfun' successfully installed. Warning message: In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) : problem copying C:\Users<computername>\Documents\R\win-library\3.6\00LOCK\xfun\libs\x64\xfun.dll to C:\Users<computername>\Documents\R\win-library\3.6\xfun\libs\x64\xfun.dll: Permission denied

Because it was facing an issue while overwriting on top of the file, I simply pasted the older file elsewhere and it was able to create a new one while installing at the location above.

> package 'xfun' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> The downloaded binary packages are in
> C:\Users<computername>\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpq0b4WV\downloaded_packages

Answer (score 0):

Try installing using `pak::pak("package-name")`. Nothing worked for me until I tried that.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**