# I am trying to install devtools on Rstudio

Tags: rstudio

I am trying to install devtools on Rstudio, and I am receiving this error message:

> install.packages("devtools")
>   trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/devtools_1.7.0.zip'
>   Content type 'application/zip' length 308736 bytes (301 Kb)
>   opened URL
>   downloaded 301 Kb

package ‘devtools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘devtools’

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\temp\Rtmpu4TtC7\downloaded_packages

> 

What is the best way to resolve.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's an error!

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570912/error-in-installation-a-r-package would help?