# Using read_excel(na = ) how do you specify more than one NA character string?

Tags: r, readxl

I'm trying to read into R an excel sheet that uses multiple values for NA (specifically, "N/A" and "n/a"). If I try to give na= a list of strings it throws an error:

```
read_excel(path = "file.xlsx",
           na = "N/A") #This works just fine

read_excel(path = "file.xlsx",
           na = c("N/A", "n/a"))

Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : expecting a single value
```

Any ideas on how to read this in with both strings converted to NA? Or am I better off doing a find/replace once the data is in R?

Comment: According to [`readxl/issues/272`](https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/272), "multiple-`na` values" is supported in the github version. (I have not yet tested it.)

Comment: Thanks r2evans, the github version is working great now

Comment: readxl::read_excel from readxl version 1.1.0 offers this feature now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you gathered, `read_excel` does not accept more than one value. Consider using `gdata::read.xls` instead.

```
gdata::read.xls("file.xlsx", na.strings = c("N/A", "n/a"))
```

**Edit**: *Note that you need to have perl installed to run this. If you're on windows you may need to specify something like `perl="C:/Perl/bin/perl.exe"` in the call to `read.xls`.*

**Edit 2**: *As @r2evans suggested in the comments, the development version of `readxl` supports multiple na values:*

```
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/readxl")
readxl::read_excel(path = "file.xlsx", na = c("N/A", "n/a"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the continued help, I just spent awhile installing perl, setting the path and running installXLSXsupport(), still giving me an empty data frame. BUT, if this github version works that will be all I wanted and more, downloading now. Thanks!

Comment: This worked perfectly. Took a bit to install the package (didn't have Rtools), and then I had to manually delete Rccp because the old version was blocking installation (this answer helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570912/error-in-installation-a-r-package). But now read_excel is doing everything I need, thanks again!