# Unable to install package forecast in R

Tags: r, package

I am trying to install package forecast in R using below command

```
install.packages("forecast")
```

, but getting message that

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/forecast_8.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2076974 bytes (2.0 MB)
downloaded 2.0 MB

package ‘forecast’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘forecast’

I manually removed package from local folder as remove.package was also not working, can anyone help me here and let me know what is the issue

Comment: Your case may be similar to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570912/error-in-installation-a-r-package