# Unable to install package Rcpp successfully in R Studio

Tags: r, installation, install.packages

I am unable to install the package "rcpp" in R Studio even though it was executed successfully. When I try to load the sasme library, it doesnt show me in the list of installed libraries.

> install.packages("Rcpp")
>   Installing package into ‘C:/Users/sk/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/Rcpp_1.0.4.6.zip'
>   Content type 'application/zip' length 3030990 bytes (2.9 MB)
>   downloaded 2.9 MB

package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘Rcpp’

> library(Rcpp)
>   Error in library(Rcpp) : there is no package called ‘Rcpp’

Comment: The troublesome part of the error message is the "cannot remove prior installation". See if the suggestions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570912/error-in-installation-a-r-package help. This doesn't seem specific to Rcpp.

Comment: Hi @MrFlick: Thank you! I closed all the R studio sessions as well as deleted the LOCK file as mentioned in the link you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install by downloading the .tar.gz file from the archive link:
https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Rcpp/
and installing this instead of directly from CRAN.

I had to install a few other libraries which were dependent on this library as well.