# Can't update packages in R

Tags: r, windows, installation, package

This all started after I tried to update `tidyr` and now I'm suddenly not able to update any of my packages in R and nothing I find online seems to work...

I have restarted my laptop, restarted R, downloaded the newest version of Rtools, updating `devtools` and tried `update.packages(ask = FALSE)`.

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/first_name.last_name/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.0/library" 

install.packages("devtools")

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/devtools_2.4.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 436566 bytes (426 KB)
downloaded 426 KB

package ‘devtools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\1\RtmpszQ0e5\downloaded_packages

devtools::install_github("tidyr")

Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace ‘cli’ 3.3.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.4.0 is required


> update.packages(ask = FALSE)

Warning: package 'boot' in library 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.0/library' will not be updated
Warning: package 'class' in library 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.0/library' will not be updated
Warning: package 'cluster' in library 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.0/library' will not be updated
Warning: package 'codetools' in library 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.0/library' will not be updated
Warning: package 'foreign' in library 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.0/library' will not be updated
 ...etc.

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/cli_3.6.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1332136 bytes (1.3 MB)
downloaded 1.3 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/dplyr_1.1.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1553403 bytes (1.5 MB)
downloaded 1.5 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/fansi_1.0.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 312643 bytes (305 KB)
downloaded 305 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/tibble_3.2.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 690261 bytes (674 KB)
downloaded 674 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/utf8_1.2.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 149996 bytes (146 KB)
downloaded 146 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/vctrs_0.6.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1335280 bytes (1.3 MB)
downloaded 1.3 MB

package ‘cli’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package ‘cli’
Warning: restored ‘cli’
package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package ‘dplyr’
Warning: restored ‘dplyr’
...etc

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\1\RtmpiAI2dx\downloaded_packages
Warning messages:
1: In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\00LOCK\cli\libs\x64\cli.dll to C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\cli\libs\x64\cli.dll: Permission denied
2: In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\00LOCK\dplyr\libs\x64\dplyr.dll to C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\dplyr\libs\x64\dplyr.dll: Permission denied
3: In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\00LOCK\fansi\libs\x64\fansi.dll to C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\fansi\libs\x64\fansi.dll: Permission denied
4: In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\00LOCK\tibble\libs\x64\tibble.dll to C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\tibble\libs\x64\tibble.dll: Permission denied
5: In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\00LOCK\utf8\libs\x64\utf8.dll to C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\utf8\libs\x64\utf8.dll: Permission denied
6: In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\00LOCK\vctrs\libs\x64\vctrs.dll to C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\vctrs\libs\x64\vctrs.dll: Permission denied


> invisible(lapply(paste0('package:', names(sessionInfo()$otherPkgs)), detach, character.only=TRUE, unload=TRUE))

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid 'name' argument
```

**UPDATE:**

After following advice from the comments and the suggested duplicate question I'm still getting this error message:

```
> install.packages("cli")
Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages

Restarting R session...

> install.packages("cli")
Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages
> install.packages("cli")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/cli_3.6.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1332136 bytes (1.3 MB)
downloaded 1.3 MB

package ‘cli’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘cli’
Warning in install.packages :
  problem copying C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\00LOCK\cli\libs\x64\cli.dll to C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\cli\libs\x64\cli.dll: Permission denied
Warning in install.packages :
  restored ‘cli’

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\1\RtmpSeabMG\downloaded_packages
```

I have also tried to remove the "00LOCK" file from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570912/error-in-installation-a-r-package):

```
> library(pacman)
Warning message:
package ‘pacman’ was built under R version 4.2.3 
> p_unlock()

No 00LOCK detected in:
 C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2
No 00LOCK detected in:
 C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.0/library
```

Comment: Hi! When you want to install a package from github, you have to indicate the profile from where it comes. Try with `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/tidyr")` .

Comment: Regarding `namespace ‘cli’ 3.3.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.4.0 is required` - you can't update a package that's currently loaded. Restart R, then `install.packages("cli")` first thing. If you still have that error, make sure your R profile doesn't load packages during start-up.

Comment: @GregorThomas, I restarted R and ran `install.packages("cli")`, but got the error message I added above in my update.

Comment: The suggested answer from the question marked as similar to mine doesn't work. I get the same error message that's in my update.

Comment: Assuming the problem is from the "00LOCK" file, can I see it/delete it if I run R as the admin?

Comment: Do you have more than one copy of R running on your computer? What if you restart your computer. then try the install? It seems something is locking that DLL file. Do you have any code in an RProfile file that runs when you start R? If you are running this right after you restart R, I'm surprised it's saying "Updating loaded packages". There should be nothing loaded at that point.

Comment: @MrFlick Restarting my pc and running `install.packages("cli")` gives me the same error: `cannot remove prior installation of package ‘cli’. Warning in install.packages: problem copying C:\Users\nathan.laspina\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\00LOCK\cli\libs\x64\cli.dll to C:\Users\nathan.laspina\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\cli\libs\x64\cli.dll: Permission denied`

Comment: I don't have more than one copy running, no. What is the "RProfile file"? I don't think so..